# Where can I configure TokenExpiryTime in wso2 for SMSOTP?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am testing and have configured wso2 Identity Server 5.7.4 with SMSOTP and VonageAPI. The system properly sends the command to the API, the phone receives the code, but once the code is entered, I receive an Authorization Failed message.

The log of the wso2 server records an error of:
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.smsotp.SMSOTPAuthenticator} -  TokenExpiryTime property is not configured in application-authentication.xml or SMS OTP Authenticator UI

I cannot find any documentation that references this property and the setup instructions do not make any mention to set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following configurations in the `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/identity/application-authentication.xml` file under the section `AuthenticatorConfig name="SMSOTP" enabled="true">`

```
    <Parameter name="TokenExpiryTime">30</Parameter>
```

Refer doc: https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-outbound-auth-sms-otp/blob/2.0.x/docs/config.md#note-if-you-already-has-lower-version-of-orgwso2carbonextensionidentityhelper-in-is_homerepositorycomponentsdropins-directory-remove-the-older-jar